# Why is my entire object serialized as Array when DataMember's Name is "length"

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a new ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application and modified the default ValuesController like this:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebSerializationTest.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/values
        public ApiResponse Get()
        {
            ApiResponse res = new ApiResponse();
            res.Length = 120;
            return res;
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class ApiResponse
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "length")]
        public int Length { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now when I do the request from a browser (with Headers set to Accept: application/json), I get this JSON:

```
[
    120
]
```

However **when I change the DataMember Name** to anything else, even **[DataMember(Name = "Length")]**
I get correct JSON:

```
{
    "Length" : 120
}
```

> Is the string "length" forbidden or what is causing this behaviour?

*Btw. I have target framework set to .NET Framework 4, but I have also tried .NET Framework 4.5.1 and the issue is still there.*

Comment: WebAPI uses JSON.NET as default JSON serializer. Can you reproduce the issue with your decorated `ApiResponse` model if you serialize it using JSON.NET?

Comment: simply use `[JsonProperty(PropertyName="length")]` instead of `DataContract` and `DataMember`.

Comment: Can not reproduce with Visual Studio 2013, .NET 4.5, Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.0.0

Comment: I would not vote to close this, as it is a bug in an addon. Many other people could easily notice the same issue.

Comment: Also, if you're looking to just translate from UpperCamelCase to lowerCamelCase, there is a native method you can set up with JSON.NET called [CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/25/asp-net-webapi-tip-3-camelcasing-json.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it is a bug in Firefox's addon called **RESTClient** which I use.

In  **Response Body(Highlight) tab** the JSON is rendered incorrectly, but in **Response Body (Raw) tab** the JSON is correct.

I have also found out it is a [known bug](https://github.com/chao/RESTClient/issues/102) which has not been fixed since 2012.